# Constructor in interface

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I am trying to come up with a way that allows me to add components of various types to a game object.

I have checked the [TypeScript documentation for interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) and have learned that TypeScript has a unique way of dealing with constructors in interfaces. Based on that, I came up with the following.

**Component setup**

```
export interface IComponentConstructor {
    new(gameObject: GameObject, ...args: any[]): IComponent;
}

export interface IComponent {
    update?(): void;
}

export const createComponent = (
    ctor: IComponentConstructor,
    gameObject: GameObject,
    ...args: any[]
): IComponent => {
    return new ctor(gameObject, args);
}
```

**PlayerComponent**

```
export class PlayerComponent implements IComponent {

    constructor(gameObject: GameObject, ...args: any[]) { }

    public update() { }
}
```

**GameObject**

```
export class GameObject {

    components: IComponent[] = [];

    public addComponent(ComponentType: IComponent, ...args: any[]) {
        const component = createComponent(
            ComponentType,
            this,
            args
        );
        
        this.components.push(component);
        return component;
    }
```

The problem is that I want to be able to pass various component types to `addComponent`, e.g. `PlayerComponent`, `EnemyComponent`, `NpcComponent`, etc.

But since it expects the passed in object to be of type `IComponentConstructor`, and those components are of type `IComponent`, it does not work:

```
Argument of type 'IComponent' is not assignable to parameter
of type 'IComponentConstructor'.
Type 'IComponent' provides no match for the signature 
'new (gameObject: GameObject, ...args: any[]): IComponent'
```

Is there a way to make this work in TypeScript?

---

PS: The following would work, but is not what I want, since I want to be able to pass `PlayerComponent` into the `addComponent` method:

```
const component = createComponent(
    PlayerComponent,
    this,
    args
);
```

Comment: You probably want to pass `*Component` itself into the `addComponent` and not a value of that type, is that correct? If so, why do you use `IComponent` and nor `IComponentConstructor`?

Comment: Why you don't use `abstract class`?

Comment: @Cerberus Hm, well, because I thought `PlayerComponent` would "be of type"  `IComponent`, since that is the interface it implements? But you are right, your solution works. But I don't understand why?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Because then I can't add the various components to the `components` array, since TypeScript would require it to be a union type from what I understand. Hence I would have to manually add to that type whenever I add another component. I think using an interface is the only feasible way here.

Comment: `PlayerComponent` as a value is not "of a type" `IComponent`. The values of type `PlayerComponent`, created by `new PlayerComponent(...)`, are, but `PlayerComponent` itself is `IComponentConstructor`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Cerberus in the comments, the solution is to change the type of `addComponent` as follows:

```
public addComponent(ComponentType: IComponentConstructor, ...args: any[]) {
    // ...
}
```