# Method with generic return type

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible to make the following `getComponent` method generic, so that I can drop the `as SkinComponent` when I call it?

I think part of the problem here may be that what I am passing in is `IComponentConstructor`, but what I want back is `IComponent`. So I'm not sure how to represent that using generics.

```js
const skinComponent = gameObject.getComponent(SkinComponent) as SkinComponent;

skinComponent.methodOnlyAvailableOnSkinComponent();
```

```js
export class GameObject {
    
    components: IComponent[];

    public getComponent(
        ComponentType: IComponentConstructor
    ): IComponent | undefined {

        return this.components.find(c => c instanceof ComponentType);
    }
}
```

---

I have tried a few different approaches, e.g. the below, but I always seem to end up with the following error.

```js
public getComponent<T extends IComponent>(
    ComponentType: IComponentConstructor<T>
): T | undefined {
    
   return this.components.find(c => c instanceof ComponentType);
}
```

```
Type 'IComponent | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'.
Type 'IComponent' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'IComponent' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T'
could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IComponent'.
```

---

PS: For `IComponentConstructor` and `IComponent`, please see my previous StackOverflow post: [Constructor in interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73174008/constructor-in-interface/73178957#73178957)

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc. Links to code available in other questions also don't count as being self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.find()` is not a generic method, and therefore does not narrow the type. This means that `array.find()` will *always* return the member type type of the array.

```
const strings: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const a = strings.find(str => str === 'a') // type is string | undefined, and not "a"
```

So `this.components.find()` will return a `IComponent` because that's the array's member type. And an `IComponent` can't be assumed to be any specific subclass of `IComponent`

---

However, `if` statements do narrow the type. So I would probably change this to a simple loop and an early return:

```
    public getComponent<T extends IComponent>(
        ComponentType: IComponentConstructor<T>
    ): T | undefined {
        for (const c of this.components) {
            if (c instanceof ComponentType) return c
        }
        return
    }
```

Now `c` is returned after an `if` statement has narrowed that type to `T`, and everything else works.

```
const gameObject = new GameObject()
const skinComponent = gameObject.getComponent(SkinComponent);
skinComponent?.methodOnlyAvailableOnSkinComponent(); // works
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSDCB7AtgB0QOwKYYC7QG9oBLCJNTHfAXmlwCcBXLaAXwFgAoXAT1RYQp02PEgwQGjYLkT0APABVoWAB64cAExiCKI3AD5otItgDuACgCUALmhKOnLqvT18oSDADiYZFgDyAEYAVljShFzQkdARUcBClHgQtjrCVADaALpG0JkA3FwxkaiMASDEwNAA5li45Kl4ispqmtp1CQbmhVGRbXoKfFjJvVRiEkzSsor6XTZ20AA+0IwYGlgAZsTYGuGc3d1rstDmceJu0IhrdAAWpAB0cbpUEJY7e28kl8ckp2AYwFgXaDDPD9fgveg1Rj0DDQYBdboOd7QCG4KEYLoOBxcdxQaAAZQA1ptgfhVOoVq14npXlFfLgrogNH4MCAeABBABuYGI4FK-gwhOJVKoVhpbxRaOgAHJiMhoGBoBAiRgpRiuFjOCcJFUfP5gqEaNAzNBvL5AiFpFZsZhtUqhY88NlKrrzQbbtVasK8OZBRgSZZ8pw7X6vbgAPy3OkMpks9lcnlgPnM30kqy5aAAegz0FMsgJECAA)

Comment: Thank you for this! I can confirm it indeed works. However, I am not quite sure why it works without specifying the `<SkinComponent>` when calling `getComponent(SkinComponent)`? I would have thought it would need to be `getComponent<SkinComponent>(SkinComponent)`? Also, out of curiosity, would it be possible to make it `getComponent<SkinComponent>()` like one could do in C#?

Comment: _"why it works without specifying the <SkinComponent> when calling getComponent"_ Because typescript generics can get their type from arguments. In this case `T` is use as part of the `ComponentType` argument's type, and the compiler can figure out what it is form there. The docs should help you understand this better: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: _"would it be possible to make it `getComponent<SkinComponent>()`"_ Nope. Typescript is just javascript with types that get removed at runtime. So, at runtime that is just `getComponent()` and the type is completely gone. So if you need to use `SkinComponent` at runtime, then it must exist at runtime, which means passing it as an argument.